# Query for fetching data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am having 2 tables

> user table

that having

```
id fname lname
1  asdf  fdg
2  asd2  ddf 
3  xsss  ss
4  frfr  dd 
5  dede  dd
```

and in userassociation  table

```
user1 associateduser
1      2
1      3
```

i want to select id,fname,lname from user table that should not include user1 and its associatedusers

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    fname,
    lname
FROM
    user
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            userassociation
        WHERE
            userassociation.user1=user.id
            AND userassociation.associateduser=user.id
    )
```

Comment: @Arion,Thanks for reply  Query is working fine but i also want to send user id dynamically

Comment: @Manish : Then just add an `AND WHERE id=yourID`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,fname,lname from `user`
where id not in (select user1 as u 
                 from userassociation 
                 union 
                 select associateduser as u 
                 from userassociation)
```